# ellipse rotation while not chaging initial appearence

Tags: c#, wpf, matrix, rotational-matrices

I need to rotate an ellipse such way that it's initial appearance not disturbing.

Ex:
Ellipse drawn
(lying down  on X-axis  ) 
( longer diameter in X-axis shorter distance in Y-axis )

after rotating 90 degrees:

My Expected result:

```
   longer diameter in X-axis 
   shorter distance in Y-axis
```

so diameter should be as it was before ,but it should give you rotation appearance.

Actual results:

```
      longer diameter part in Y-axis 
      shorter distance part in X-axis )
```

I'm not allowed to post images here for showing clearly.

Thanks

Comment: If you rotate it by 90 degree then the output will be what you are getting right now. If you rotate it by 180 degree then you will get what you expect.

Comment: Do you want to rotate the ellipse's translation vector? Then you should just calculate the new translation. You can't apply a rotation matrix to the entire ellipse.

Comment: @Nico  do i need to calculate for every pixel?

Comment: Your question does not make sense... how can you have a 'squashed circle' type `Ellipse` that keeps its shape after rotating 90 degrees? It's simply not possible. Perhaps you just want the `Ellipse.Background` to rotate? Either way, if you want an answer, you'd better edit your question and *clearly* explain what you want.

Comment: @Sheridan .. i set up Ellipse.Fill with the image. i didn't try i in this way ( rotating image) ... i will try to apply rotation transformation to the image.. am I right ?